# Can't uninstall module that depends on custom field type in use

Tags: 8, entities, installation

**Drupal 8**

Using [Yoast](https://www.drupal.org/project/yoast_seo), I've removed it from all my content types but I can't uninstall because it says --> `The Yoast SEO status & focused keywords field type is used in the following field: taxonomy_term.field_yoast_seo`, which I did not create nor is it visible via `Structure > Taxonomy`.

[image]

Looking into the DB, there's over 51 matches for 'field_yoast_seo', but I can see where it is created:

[image]

It's a table. I don't know if I can just go ahead and delete it without it backfiring on me. Has anyone tried it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Be sure to backup your database before you try out what I did, just in case.**

After looking everywhere I decided to go for it and delete it from the database. I also opened an [issue](https://www.drupal.org/node/2831056) in the Drupal Project for Yoast SEO.

I used PHPMyAdmin to search any occurrences of `"field_yoast_seo"`, these are the steps (and order) I took:

- Deleted appearances in `cache_` tables
- Deleted rest of appearances
- Emptied the table `taxonomy_term_field_yoast_seo`
- Deleted the table `taxonomy_term_field_yoast_seo` (I checked there were no dependencies to the rest of the data base)
- Cleared Caches
- Ran cron manually
- Uninstalled Yoast Seo (after all of the above, the check box was available and I could uninstall)
- Manually removed the module from `/httpdocs/modules`

Leaving the answer here in case anyone else runs into this.

Answer (score 2):

If a module define a field type, it can't be uninstalled if you have a field of this type. This is not related which tables are in the database, and deleting tables in the database wont resolve this.

What you need to do, is to delete the field yourself. Drupal doesn't want to this automatically, as it could mean data loss. From the message you get the field name `taxonomy_term.field_yoast_seo`. This machine name is structured as `ENTITY_TYPE.FIELD_NAME`, so the field you need to delete is on a taxonomy term. It doesn't tell which vocabulary it's located on, but hopefully you can find it manually and resolve it

Comment: I didn't create the taxonomy term, and it's not visible via Structure > Taxonomy .

Comment: Either way, I took your advice and did it manually, though not from UI (since I couldn't find the taxonomy term) but rather from database. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to uninstall this module by going to admin/config/yoast_seo
Unselecting everything under: Configure Real-time SEO by bundles
running Cron
Then the tick box for Real-time SEO became available in Uninstall